# Error while using Edwardvanraak barcode scanner library

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am trying to add a barcode scanner into my app using the Edwardvanraak library but I am getting  an error.

This is my error log:

```
   03-16 12:33:11.023 25919-25919/com.myapp.siva E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.myapp.siva, PID: 25919
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.zzd$zza
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.zzd.zzIg(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.edwardvanraak.materialbarcodescanner.MaterialBarcodeScannerBuilder.buildMobileVisionBarcodeDetector(MaterialBarcodeScannerBuilder.java:237)
                                                                          at com.edwardvanraak.materialbarcodescanner.MaterialBarcodeScannerBuilder.build(MaterialBarcodeScannerBuilder.java:221)
                                                                          at com.myapp.siva.bus.QrCodeScanningActivity.startScan(QrCodeScanningActivity.java:44)
                                                                          at com.myapp.siva.bus.QrCodeScanningActivity.onCreate(QrCodeScanningActivity.java:21)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5555)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
```

Below is my code for QR code scanning. I tried adding the same code in a new project and it works fine. However I am unable to resolve the error in the main project:

```
package com.myapp.siva.bus;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.edwardvanraak.materialbarcodescanner.MaterialBarcodeScanner;
import com.edwardvanraak.materialbarcodescanner.MaterialBarcodeScannerBuilder;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.myapp.siva.R;

public class QrCodeScanningActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Barcode barcodeResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr_code_scanning);

    startScan();
}

private void startScan() {
    /**
     * Build a new MaterialBarcodeScanner
     */
    final MaterialBarcodeScanner materialBarcodeScanner = new MaterialBarcodeScannerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withEnableAutoFocus(true)
            .withBleepEnabled(false)
            .withBackfacingCamera()
            .withCenterTracker()
            .withText("Scanning...")
            .withResultListener(new MaterialBarcodeScanner.OnResultListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Barcode barcode) {
                    barcodeResult = barcode;
                    String result = barcodeResult.displayValue;
                    Toast.makeText(QrCodeScanningActivity.this, ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  //                        result.setText(barcode.rawValue);
                }
            })
            .build();
    materialBarcodeScanner.startScan();
}
```

}

I tried resolving the error,but i am unable to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Please add the Google Mobile vision dependency and it will work fine.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
```